# Building image from multiple docker hub images or private repo docker

Tags: linux, docker, containers, dockerfile

i am able to create the `dockerFile` where i could do the stuffs. Its like i might have 10-15 apps running for now and more to go. 
my `dockerFile`

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN installing necessary softwares
```

The thing i am trying is installing the softwares via images too. Like for

```
php7.0 
 FROM ubuntu:16.04
   FROM php:7.0-cli
    RUN installing necessary softwares
```

So currently i am making docker file for each project and do like `FROM source RUN install this and that` and same thing i have to do for the rest. Lets suppose i want to change the version of php for all 10 servers. i have to open file and edit. Any good suggestion to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use ENV variables? Like

```
... 
ENV PHP_VERSION=7.0 
RUN apt-get install php=$PHP_VERSION
...
```

Or maybe use templating language which is offered by tool [Rocker](https://github.com/grammarly/rocker)